# Joining the same table to get the information

Tags: mysql, join

I have a table like

```
Name     Spouse
---------------

John     Smitha

Bob      Neetha

Neetha   Bob

Mona     Jack

Smitha   John

Jack     Mona
```

and I want results as below using joins in MySQL.

```
Name     Spouse
---------------

John     Smitha

Bob      Neetha

Mona     Jack
```

(i.e. the couple should be selected only once)

Comment: without giving you the exact query, google "sql alias self join"

Comment: The way that you have the data setup John and Smitha both have a spousal relationship to each other, you need another field to indicate who the primary's are.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have a IsPrimary field.

You could easily achieve this with the following query.

```
SELECT P.NAME, S.NAME As SpouseName
FROM PEOPLE P
LEFT JOIN PEOPLE S ON P.Spouse = S.Spouse -- You should have a PK/FK relasionship here (SouseId) and not join on a name string
WHERE P.IsPrimary = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

a way to do it like that

```
    SELECT `Name`, `Spouse`
    FROM Table1
    WHERE `Name` <= `Spouse`
```

[demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b90ac2/25)